# flexslider slides not chaning on thumbnail click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

im using flexslider to display a slideshow with thumbnails. recently i added a css code to show an overlay when the thumbnail is hovered. But the problem is when i click on the thumbnail nothing happens.

```
.flex-control-nav li{
    position: relative;
}
.flex-control-nav li img{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.flex-control-nav li:hover img{
    opacity: .5;
}
.flex-control-nav li::after{
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background-image: url(//i.imgur.com/xMS5K4O.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}
.flex-control-nav li:hover::after{
    top: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}
```

but when i remove the  `content: " ";` block it seems to work or else nothing happens when the thumbnails clicked.

Here is a demo of the slider **[slider demo](http://vidznet.com/slider/)**

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The slider probably has it's own event handlers, and those aren't set up to work with your custom overlays ?

Comment: @adeneo the problem is that this works out of the template http://jsfiddle.net/r4uthech/2/ but it breaks when i add to my template. I have been going through but i cant figure out whats causing it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:after` to the `img` element, change `li:after` to `img:after`